Create a unique identifier and a copied identifier that exists across rows
I'm working with a dataset that has unique identifiers across two columns. The first column is the current ID and the last column is the previous ID. Each row has a unique combination of ID and previous ID. I'd like to be able to create a unique identifier for all IDs in a group.
Let's call the first column ID and the second column Copied_ID. The data looks something like this:
library(dbplyr)
library(tidyverse)
  
data <- tibble(
     ID = c("1a2b", "3c4d", "5e6f", "7g8h", "9i0j", "1k2l", "3m4n", "5o6p"),
     Copied_ID = c("3c4d", "5e6f", "7g8h", NA, "1k2l", "3m4n", "5o6p", NA)
   )

data

For each ID group, the last version is the most recent, and so doesn't have a copied ID value. The 3 previous versions are other iterations of the same ID.
I'd like the output to look like this:
grouped_data <- tibble(
     ID = c("1a2b", "3c4d", "5e6f", "7g8h", 
            "9i0j", "1k2l", "3m4n", "5o6p"),
     Group_ID = c("Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1",
                  "Group 2", "Group 2", "Group 2", "Group 2")
   )

grouped_data

The actual IDs in my dataset are randomly generated 36 character strings in the following format: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX (8 char - 4 char - 4 char - 12 char). This means I can't use functions like str_detect to identify numerical commonalities to identify groups.
An important caveat here: the data is stored in a Microsoft SQL Server. I can bring the values into memory using collect() but I'd prefer to identify a solution to this issue using dbplyr to translate R syntax to a SQL query.

Since you mentioned data is stored in ms-server and you wanted to translate R syntax to sql, I created sample set of data based on the example that you provided and tested.
I am however unsure if you wanted to use dplyr only, let me know.
Here is the sql I used and tested on sample data :
Fiddle
WITH RecursiveCTE AS (
    -- Base case: Select rows where Copied_ID is NULL 
    SELECT ID, Copied_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Group_ID
    FROM ID_Copies
    WHERE Copied_ID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive case: Join the table with itself to trace backward through the Copied_ID chain
    SELECT t.ID, t.Copied_ID, r.Group_ID
    FROM ID_Copies t
    INNER JOIN RecursiveCTE r
        ON t.Copied_ID = r.ID
)
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Group_ID
FROM RecursiveCTE
ORDER BY Group_ID;

Output :

EDITED : WITHOUT RECURSION(Since Recursion is not supported)
caveat : Below code will work if you the length of chain is 4, if you need to use length more than 4, please extend the steps as Step5 .. etc. For testing I have extended your dataset and used extra Group3 as well, you can find it in Fiddle.
WITH Step1 AS (
    -- Step 1: Identify the rows where Copied_ID is NULL (the most recent ID in each chain)
    SELECT ID, Copied_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Group_ID
    FROM ID_Copies
    WHERE Copied_ID IS NULL
),
Step2 AS (
    -- Step 2: Trace back to the previous IDs by joining to the table based on Copied_ID
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.Copied_ID, s1.Group_ID
    FROM ID_Copies t1
    JOIN Step1 s1 ON t1.Copied_ID = s1.ID
),
Step3 AS (
    -- Step 3: Join again to trace one step further in the chain
    SELECT t2.ID, t2.Copied_ID, s2.Group_ID
    FROM ID_Copies t2
    JOIN Step2 s2 ON t2.Copied_ID = s2.ID
),
Step4 AS (
    -- Step 4: Continue to trace backward for one more step
    SELECT t3.ID, t3.Copied_ID, s3.Group_ID
    FROM ID_Copies t3
    JOIN Step3 s3 ON t3.Copied_ID = s3.ID
)
-- Finally, combine all steps to return the IDs with their corresponding Group_ID
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Group_ID
FROM Step1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Group_ID
FROM Step2
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Group_ID
FROM Step3
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Group_ID
FROM Step4
ORDER BY Group_ID;



Thanks for this solution. I'm having a difficult time translating the recursive join into R syntax. Do you know how I might do that with dbplyr?

can you not use this query as part of dbplyr ? using result <- dbGetQuery(con, query) ?

And just a note, I modified your query with the appropriate column and table names, and received the following error: "Recursive common table expressions are not supported in this version." So unfortunately it doesn't look like your solution will work with the database we're using.

I see, which version of ms-server you are using ? I will try and check if I can find an alternate way of the query instead of using recursion

Looks like we're using MS SQL Server 2017. I also have the option of running it on Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

See the Edited part without recursion, only caveat is if the length of chain changes, you would need to add step 5,step6 etc

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Use a mutate and split the int off the float and paste it together with 'Group '
data |>
  dplyr::mutate(Group_ID=paste('Group ',sapply(strsplit(ID,"\\."), `[`, 1),sep=''))

If its more involved than that, the sample data would be better off refecting that

Thanks, but unfortunately I can't split the data by number since the IDs are, in reality, 36 character randomly generated alphanumeric strings. I just edited my original post to hopefully better reflect this.
